# CamlQuery not returning any items

Tags: 2010, caml-query

I'm trying to build a CamlQuery that returns all documents in my /public/ folder but I keep getting the same error. Am I formatting the query incorrectly?

```
{"One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields."}    System.ApplicationException {Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException}
```

This is the query where `meta="Test"`

```
"<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name=”Key_x0020_Topics”/><Value Type='SPFieldLookupMulti'>" + meta + "</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>";
```

This is the HTML from the form which is using the "Key Topics" item but I don't believe I am formatting it correctly/

```
<tr>
        <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="165px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Key_x0020_Topics"></a>Key Topics</h3></td>
        <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="450px" id="SPFieldLookupMulti">
        <!-- FieldName="Key Topics"
             FieldInternalName="Key_x0020_Topics"
             FieldType="SPFieldLookupMulti"
          -->
            <a href="/Lists/Key%20Topics/DispForm.aspx?ID=6&RootFolder=*">Test</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I think the Value Type should be LookupMulti instead of SPFieldLookupMulti. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208078/caml-query-for-lookup-field-with-multi-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with following

```
"<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Key_x0020_Topics'/><Value Type='SPFieldLookupMulti'>" + meta + "</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>";
```